# Calling form validation function from new button

Tags: 7, forms

I've attached a **Process** button on the node edit form. But on clicking it - in it's validation function `form_set_error` is not working.

In my form_alter I've this code:

```
$form['buttons']['process'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Process',
            '#validate' => array('disavow_process_validate'),
        );

        $form['#validate'][] = 'disavow_validate';
```

So on pressing "Process" button validator function `disavow_process_validate` is called with $form and &$form_state. But `form_set_error` and assigning values in the $form_state are not working as working in the normal validation function `disavow_validate`

**What could be the problem?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See below example which works perfectly...

```
function drup_custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == "page_node_form" && arg(2) == "edit") {
    $form['buttons']['process'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Process',
            '#validate' => array('disavow_process_validate'),
    );
  }
}

function disavow_process_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  form_set_error('title', 'Something wrong here !');
}
```

Please update what you are trying to do inside validate function..

Comment: Sorry it was some typo.